# sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters sql 2005 running every 20 seconds

Tags: sql

A little background info:
We are running SQL Server 2005 SP2 on a server with Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2.
When I run profiler I notice that EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters is running every 20 seconds.

Here is what the profiler is running every 20 seconds:
SELECT N'Testing Connection...'
go
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters
go

What I have done so far:
I have deleted all the demo alerts on the system.

Possible answers:
I was wondering if a service pack 3 or 4 on 2005 might fix this issue?
or is there something I can set in the registry or in sql itself?
or is there a patch for Windows Server 2003 that might help?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly this always happens with SQL 2005.  I don't thing that a newer service pack will fix this.  Though you should upgrade to the latest service pack if possible.

Comment: Let me try to update to SP4 and I will let you know.  Thank you for the help so far.